# Python - .format with {} touching other characters

Tags: python

I am trying to use the ".format" with a string to insert values in a for loop. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as fout:
    for element in range (0, 5):
        line1 = 'Icon_{}.NO = Icon_Generic;'.format(element)
        fout.write(line1)
```

When I do this it chokes. My best guess is that it doesn't like the underscore directly beside the {} ("_{}"). Is this correct? Is there a good workaround for this?

I have used something like this and it works:

```
line1 = Icon_Generic.NO = Icon_%02d.NO;\n' % element
```

However, if I want to do a large multiline bunch of code using the "% element" doesn't work well.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** As best I can tell I'm using Python 3.3

This is the error I get (using IDLE 3.3.2 shell):

```
>>> with open('p_text.txt', 'w') as fout:
for element in range(0, 5):
    template = """if (!Icon_{0}.notFirstScan) {""".format(element)
    fout.write(template)
    fout.write('\n\n')
input('press enter to exit')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#13>", line 3, in <module>
template = """if (!Icon_{0}.notFirstScan) {""".format(element)
ValueError: Single '{' encountered in format string
```

Comment: Chokes? Do you get any error?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.6 or older perhaps?

Comment: The line you say works should have raised a SyntaxError... (no closing quote.)

Comment: @sberry: No, Python 2.6 supports `str.format()` too, but not the implicit numbering the format here uses.

Comment: I am going out on a limb and assume that you are using Python 2.6. Use `'Icon_{0}.NO = Icon_Generic;'.format(element)` (number your positional placeholders).

Comment: You need to escape the last brace if you want to print it, putting a double: """if (!Icon_{0}.notFirstScan) {{"""

Comment: @xbello Thank you! My problem was way off what I though it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the final opening brace that's given you the problem, as indicated by the error message: a "Single `'{'` encountered". If you need literal curly braces in the formatted string, you must escape them by doubling up (`'{{'`) wherever you mean them to be literals:

```
template = """if (!Icon_{0}.notFirstScan) {{""".format(element)
                                          ^ escape the literal '{'
```

---

Note that this is true for closing curly braces (`}`) as well!

```
>>> print('{{{0}}}'.format('text within literal braces'))
{text within literal braces}
```